# SQL Server Database Design - 1 Table vs 2 Tables

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

I have a table named `Report` and another named `ReportRights`. The purpose of these tables are to restrict access to a report based on a user or user group.

The Report Rights table is

- ReportRightsId (int - Surrogate Key)
- ReportId (int - Foreign Key to Report)
- UserId (int - null FK to Users)
- GroupId (int - null FK to Groups)
- HasAccess (bit default 0)

The issue with this is that I want to add a Unique Constraint to ReportId+UserId as well as to ReportId+GroupId but in this table structure I cannot because ReportId 1, UserId 1, Group Id NULL, and trying to add a permission for report id 2 trips the reportid 1 groupid null unique constraint.

Is this bad design? Should I have 2 tables: ReportGroupRights and ReportUserRights instead? If i were to make a front-end UI they would both be managed by the same 'grid' so 1 table makes sense to me...but the inability to enforce only 1 user record or only 1 group record is problematic.

What is the best practice for this problem?

Comment: Should use two tables

Comment: @PeterHe  Can you point to a particular article or standard that denotes this scenario and the best practice using two tables?

Comment: If you need to reach 3NF, which usually the minimum for OLTP system, you will need to have two tables. One works but not meet even the 1nf, which requires each row has a key (the artificial id is not the key)

Comment: Got it - Thanks for the information @PeterHe

Answer (score 0):

It isn't bad design.

Make `GroupId` nullable, so you can as well enter permissions for user only.

Also, unique constraint should be on three columns together: `ReportId`, `UserId`, `GroupId`.

So you can allow more then one report per user/group.

Comment: The one issue with this solution is that i believe it would allow the following 2 records:
ReportId = 1, UserId=5, GroupId = NULL
ReportId = 1, UserId=5, GroupId=6      

This would then lead to 'hasaccess' ambiguity for user 5. But I think this still might work as we are on a deny-first rule. So if user 5 has a deny record anywhere it doesnt matter if they have access records in other places. This may work Thanks!